# updating column view from gridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview

```
SELECT  
    matno,
    MAT_NAME,
    rawpkgno,
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [CURRDATE],
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [previous_day],
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [Last_date]
FROM 
    invorder
WHERE
    invorder.strno =54009
    OR [invorder.deldate] IS NULL
GROUP BY
    matno,
    MAT_NAME,
    rawpkgno
```

My ouput in gridview is as follows

```
matno    MAT_NAME     rawpkgno       CURRDATE     previous_day      Last_date
Edit      1          REGULAR BUNS      0             125                  11
Edit      3          BIG MAC BUNS      0              29    
Edit      4          MAC FRIES        551             28
```

Now when I select edit I should be able to edit **CURRDATE**.How can I do it can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx.cs page do like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string query = string.Empty;
    string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["MAT_Name"].ToString();       
    TextBox CURRDATE = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCURRDATE") as TextBox;

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tableName set CURRDATE='" + CURRDATE.Text + "' where MAT_Name='" + id + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
   // here you bind your gridview
}
```

and to cancel that update

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind gridview       
}
```

or you can also refer to that link

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html